# Question about combing the sum() with zip()

Tags: python

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[3,4,5,2]
c=[60,70,80]
sum(zip(a,b,c),())
```

what's the logic for the sum function here? why does it return a single tuple? especially why the following won't work

```
sum(zip(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Hint: Break this into parts. Do you know what `zip(a,b,c)` means?

Comment: It's using concatenation, that's how `+` works with `tuple` objects, which is what `zip` objects yield. You should *never* use this though, it is highly inefficient.

Comment: Also, checkout out `help(sum)` and notice it has a `start` argument with a default value.

Answer (score 4):

The sum() function, simply concatenates items together with "+" and an initial value. Likewise, the zip() function produces tupled items together. Explicitly:

```
list(zip(a,b,c))    # [(1, 3, 60), (2, 4, 70), (3, 5, 80)]
sum([1,2,3],0)      # 0 + 1 + 2 + 3
sum(zip(a,b,c),())  # () + (1,3,60) + (2,4,70) + (3,5,80)
```

Hope this helps explain the sum() and zip() functions. zip() can be tricky to see what it is doing since it produces an iterator instead of an answer. If you want to see what zip() does, wrap it in a list().

The sum(zip(a,b,c)) fails because the default initial value is 0. Hence, python tried to do 0 + (1,3,60) + ..., which fails because a 0 cannot be added to a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are useful in resolving any confusion, but perhaps the result you might be looking for is achieved by doing this:

```py
sum(a+b+c)
```

because the `+` operator when applied to lists, concatenates them into a single list whereas zip does not

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` does not do what you think it does. `sum()` will add the items of its input and return the result. In your case, you want to sum numbers from 3 lists. `zip()` returns tuples containing elements of the same index from the inputs, and when the result of this is passed to sum, it concatenates the tuples, leaving you with your undesired result. The fix is to use `itertools.chain` to combine the lists, then use `sum` to sum the numbers in those lists.

To show exactly how `zip()` works, an example should be useful:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = [1, 2, 3]
list(zip(a, b)) -> [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

`zip` returned a generator of tuples (converted to a list here), each containing the element from each input that corresponds to the index of the tuple in the result, i.e, list(zip(a, b))[index] == (a[index], b[index])

What you want is this:

```
sum(itertools.chain(a, b, c))
```

EDIT: Make sure to `import itertools` first.